# Position and print PDFs

Tags: pdf, printing

I am searching for a software to position and print PDFs. I'm pretty happy with the print dialog of Adobe Reader and Acrobat. What I'm missing is some kind of position feature as seen in Photoshop.

Acrobat only allows you to print with the object centered. But if I want to print only a small object onto a larger piece of paper I might like to print it starting from the top-left.

As Photoshop is not the ideal solution due to rastering the pdf when opening I'm searching for a software that can handle this. It should be able to handle the various Adobe specifications and ISO standardizations.

Print dialog of Adobe Acrobat. Notice how the image can only be printed centered.
[image: Print dialog of Adobe Acrobat]

Print dialog of Adobe Photoshop. I can move the image now, e.g. to the top-left.
[image: Print dialog of Adobe Photoshop]

Comment: I remember Foxit PDF Reader had such feature. I used to add page margin to push the content the way I wanted. Give it a try. I used Foxit Phantompdf version to edit the pdf before printing. But the freeware version should do fine. I like it more that adobe and it's faster.

Comment: Workaround: You can convert the PDF to a high density PNG using [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/), then print it with photoshop: `convert -density 600x600 INPUT.pdf -quality 100 OUTPUT.png`. At 600dpi, I don't think you'd notice a difference in quality (I've used it before for images on an `A0` poster)

Comment: Thanks for your input! Another workaround I found to specifically start printing from the top-left uses the printing dialog of Foxit PDF Reader which allows you to (de-)select an 'auto-center' option.

Comment: @tetradop Might be a good idea to post that as an answer if it solved the issue

Comment: @Timmy It's not really a solution as it still lacks what I want/need. It allows to either print the pdf centered or starting from the top-left. But it doesn't allow moving the pdf in the print area.

Answer (score 0):

Just did a trial run in Firefox and it appears to do what you need.